# Redirexting after X seconds in Page-Like-DIVs architecture

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

I have an Android/Phonegap app that uses different  tags instead of several .html pages. this  elements are linket to each-other.
How do I make so that when you go to the second page (second div) and click nothing, afret 5 seconds you are redirected ro third div. with multiple .html files architecture I used

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="3; url=http://youtube.com">
```

but this dos not work here.
Here is a page like I have:

```
 ﻿<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <script> function show(shown, hidden) {   document.getElementById(shown).style.display='block';   document.getElementById(hidden).style.display='none';   return false; } </script> </head> <body>

  <div id="Page1">
     Content of page 1
    <a href="#" onclick="return show('Page2','Page1');">Show page 2</a>   </div>

  <div id="Page2" style="display:none">
    Content of page 2
    <a href="#" onclick="return show('Page3','Page2');">Show page 3</a>    </div>
     <div id="Page3" style="display:none">
    Content of page 3
    <a href="#" onclick="return show('Page1','Page3');">Show page 1</a>    </div>

</body> </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code:

```
﻿<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = loadPage();
function loadPage(){
    var window_hash = window.location.hash;
    var default_page_id = "page1";
    if(window_hash.length > 1){
        var page_name = window_hash.substr(1);
        document.getElementById(page_name).style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById(default_page_id).style.display = "block";
    }
}
</script> 
</head>
<body>
    <div id="page1" style="display:none">
        <a name="page1"></a>
        Content of page 1
        <a href="#page2">Show page 2</a>
    </div>
    <div id="page2" style="display:none">
        <a name="page2"></a>
        Content of page 2
        <a href="#page3">Show page 3</a>
    </div>
    <div id="page3" style="display:none">
        <a name="page3"></a>
        Content of page 3
        <a href="#page1">Show page 1</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

You use the  (anchor tag) with the "name" attribute at the beginning of each section.
You hide all the sections.
When the user clicks on any of the buttons, the page will reload with the specific hashtag.
In Javascript, when the page loads, you call a function ("loadPage()") which reads the hashtag and show this specific page. If there's no hashtag, then it'll show the default page in this case, it's "page1".